# Is it possible to overwrite existing local xml file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, filesystems

I have been successfully using FileReader to parse some XML data to HTML page from a local file. If I make changes to the DOM, I can successfully parse the data back to an XML file, but if I try to overwrite the file that was used to read, it does not successfully download. If I save the file with a different name, it successfully downloads.

I use FileReader like this from a browse/input selector:

```
function handleFileSelection(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
```

Then if I make changes, I save the data like this:

```
var blob = new Blob(
    arrayOfUnits,
    { type: "text/xml" }
    );
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Units.xml');
```

I feel like the FileReader either has the file locked, or perhaps JavaScript cannot overwrite local files?

I have tried using: `FileReader.abort()` which seems to be like `FileReader.close()` in java, but this didn't fix my issue.

Any help is appreciated, I am new to using JavaScript with local file system.

Comment: I haven't personally messed with local file system on javascript but this may help: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-copy-rename-move
Also, it would get a bit confusing as to where this file would actually get saved since it will probably default to your browsers temp file directory.

Answer (score 0):

FileReader won't write to the file system. You need FileWriter to do so.

Comment: That's not my problem. I am able to successfully write a file with a different name to the local filesystem, I cannot overwrite the current file that is being read.